# divide uitableviewcell into horizontal bar graph ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, color-codes

I have an array containing double values in the ViewController. I want to plot these values in a tableviewcell depending on the value. the actual values shouldnt appear as text. It should be replaced by a color value from yellow to red with yellow being the lowest value in the array and red being the highest value in the array.
 Eg: 5,10,15,30,20,2,1 
 should be represented in the cell as "light yellow,yellow,orange, red, darker orange, lighter yellow, very light yellow"
I rather prefer small CGRect to gradients.something similar to the F3BarGuage.

In the below code my array will be 10,11,12,13,14,30,29,28,27,26.(I think)

I want to color code this with 30 being red and 10 being yellow and all other values taking a gradient in between and display it horizontally in a view inside a tableCell as the background color or a subview (really doesnt matter).

There is not much. just an array with values only. and no functionality is needed just display the valuers as colors in a tablecell.

P.S. I havent tried anything cause I dont know how to start. I have only changed background colors as a whole not subdivide one cell and then have colors

*************Code***************

```
TableViewCell.m
@implementation TableViewCell


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

----------------------------------
ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

+ (instancetype) createViewController;

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *values;

@end
--------------------------
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for ( int i = 10; i<15; i++){

          [self.values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i]];
    }
    for ( int j = 30; j>25; j--){

          [self.values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:j]];
    }


    UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    tableView.rowHeight = 50;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
 */


// ******************** Class Methods ********************
#pragma mark - Class Methods

+ (instancetype) createViewController {
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

}

#pragma mark- Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.valueLabel.text = [values componentsJoinedByString:@" , "];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please share what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using :

in cellForRowAtindexPath:

for (i=0; i<[currentRowArray count];i++){

```
    UILabel *temp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 25, 35)];
    currentValue = [currentRowArray objectAtIndex:i];
    temp.text = [currentValue stringValue];
    temp.backgroundColor = [self transistion3value:[currentValue doubleValue] maximumValue:maxValue]; // maxValue is a double indicating the maximum at this row
    [cell.View addSubview:temp];
```

-(float)transition:(float)value :(float)maximum :(float)start_point :(float)end_point{

```
return start_point + ((end_point - start_point)*value)/maximum;
```

}

-(UIColor *)transistion3value:(float)value maximumValue:(float)max{

```
float s1,s2,s3,e1,e2,e3,r1,r2,r3;

s1=0; s2=255; s3=0.0; // start - green color
e1=255.0; e2=0.0; e3=0.0; // end - red color

r1=[self transition:value :max :s1 :e1];
r2=[self transition:value :max :s2 :e2];
r3=[self transition:value :max :s3 :e3];

return [UIColor colorWithRed:r1/255.0  green:r2/255.0 blue:r3/255.0 alpha:1];
```

}